# Railsで二次元配列をデータベースに保存したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails上で

```
[
  [“国語“, "1", “B”, "2019"],
  [“数学”, "2", “A”, "2019"],
  [“理科”, "2", "Ｂ", "2017"],
  [“社会”, "2", "Ｃ", "2019"],
  [“美術”, "2", "Ａ", "2016"],
  ["情報", "2", "Ｓ", "2017”]
]
```

このような二次元配列から要素を一つずつ取り出してCurriculum.newでデータベースに保存したいと考えているのですが、コードのイメージがつかないため、どなたかご教授していただけないでしょうか。
データベースの構造は以下のように考えております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

実行したわけじゃないのでミスがあるかもですが

db/seeds.rb にこんな感じに書いて `rake db:seed` でダメですか？

```rb
bulk_arrays = [
  [“国語“, "1", "B", "2019"],
  [“数学”, "2", "A", "2019"],
  [“理科”, "2", "Ｂ", "2017"],
  [“社会”, "2", "Ｃ", "2019"],
  [“美術”, "2", "Ａ", "2016"],
  ["情報", "2", "Ｓ", "2017"]
]

bulk_values = bulk_arrays.map{|r|
  # カラム名は適宜変更してください
  Curriculum.new {
    授業名: r[0],
    単位数: r[1],
    年度:   r[3]
  }
}

Curriculum.import bulk_values
```

---

モデルが既に定義されてるのでテーブルはすでにあるものと思ってますが
なければテーブルもマイグレーションで作る必要があります

`rails g migration create_curriculums`

でできたマイグレーションファイル db/migrate/xxxxxx_create_curriculums に

```
create_table :curriculums do |t|
  t.string '授業名'  # 追加
  t.string '単位数'  # 追加
  t.sting  '年度'    # 追加
end
```

とかいて
`rails db:migrate`
とうてばテーブルもできると思います

Comment: 返信遅れまして申し訳ありません。
２次元配列の要素の数が一定ではないので、eachで回すようなコードを考えていたのですが、ご教授いただけますでしょうか？